# Is it possible to open encrypted sparseimage files from MacOS X on Windows?

Tags: windows, encryption, sparseimage

Windows programs [MacDrive Pro](http://www.mediafour.com/products/macdrive/pro) and [TransMac](http://www.asy.com/scrtm.htm) are capable to open MacOS X .sparseimage files.

Does it include **encrypted** sparseimage files ?
Are there other programs to open such files ?

Comment: The MacDrive Pro app has a free trial... Try it.

Comment: Pro is the only version that supports sparseimage files, so no it does not do encrypted sparseimage files, I could only find a possible solution for Linux....https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3038689?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Unfortunately java-written dmgextractor (dmgx) does not support sparseimage files.

Comment: From MacDrive Pro support: "No, we do not support encrypted image files of any kind in MacDrive at this time."